# How to play different music signals in each ear jack simultaneously using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am writing a code in MATLAB to listen to a song in left side of earphones and an other song in the right side of the earphones.

```
    [x, Fs] = audioread('S1.mp3');
    [y,Fs] = audioread('S2.mp3');
    sound([x;y] , Fs );
```

This is the code I tried to develop. But it doesn't give me the intended ouput. The songs play one after the other. And both the pieces of the earphone play the same song.

```
    sound([x;y] , Fs );
```

This one works when I create a signal(like sine signal, exponential signal etc.).
Why isn't this working for audioread ?

Comment: You are concatenating them. Add them.

Comment: How do we exactly do that?

Comment: Well, if they are in the same sampling rate `Fs`, the symbol `+` adds numbers. Otherwise you need to interpolate first.

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with the GUIDE, a figure, the compiler etc.

Comment: For stereo playback, you need to concatenate the signals, but *horizontally* rather than vertically. Change to `sound([x,y], Fs);` with a comma `,` instead of a semicolon `;`.

Comment: @hideousintrovert Also, make sure that `x` and `y` are column vectors before concatenating them horizontally. If not, convert them to column vectors (i.e. monophonic) with `x = mean(x, 2); y = mean(y, 2);`